# R reduce/combine columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe and would like to merge two columns into one, if two of the cells have the same value.

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8  X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24
1 20 30 40 54 64 74 88 98 108 122 132 142 168 178 188 202 212 222 236 246 256 270 280 290
5  2  4  6  2  4  6  2  4   6   2   4   6   2   4   6   2   4   6   2   4   6   2   4   6
6  6  6  6 13 13 13 20 20  20  27  27  27   6   6   6  13  13  13  20  20  20  27  27  27
```

Thats the dataset I have. I would like to merge two columns if the elements in row 5,6 are the same by combining what ever is in row 1, e.g. the above dataset would become

```
   X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7       X8       X9        X10       X11       X12 
1 (20,168) (30,178) (40,188) (54,202) (64,212) (74,222) (88,236) (98,246) (108,256) (122,270) (132,280) (142,290)
5  2        4        6        2        4        6        2        4        6         2         4         6
6  6        6        6        13       13       13       20       20       20        27        27        27
```

Thanks in advance
EDIT: changed rows to column

Comment: How do you decide on which rows to operate on? Also, you are combining columns here, rather rows.

Comment: you're completely right. I mixed up rows and columns.

Ehh, honestly no idea. Start from the left and remove columns which where already part of a merge?

Comment: I mean, you only have 3 rows in your real data set and you always want to operate on the second and third row to find dupes?

Comment: There are more rows, but yes for this I only ever have 3 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could create a grouping variable ('gr') by `paste`ing the 2nd and 3rd rows.  Then, we `split` the sequence of column with 'gr' to get a `list` output.  Subset the first row of 'df1' based on the column index, `paste` the elements (`toString` is a convenient wrapper for `paste(., collapse=', ')`, and to add some extra formatting with parentheses we can either use `paste` or `sprintf`), `unsplit` and assign the output to the first row of 'df1'

```
gr <-  paste(df1[2,], df1[3,])

lst <- split(seq_along(df1), gr)
df1[1,] <- unsplit(lapply(lst, function(x)
                 sprintf('(%s)', toString(df1[1,x]))) , gr)
df1
#        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6        X7
#1 (20, 168) (30, 178) (40, 188) (54, 202) (64, 212) (74, 222) (88, 236)
#5         2         4         6         2         4         6         2
#6         6         6         6        13        13        13        20
#         X8         X9        X10        X11        X12       X13       X14
#1 (98, 246) (108, 256) (122, 270) (132, 280) (142, 290) (20, 168) (30, 178)
#5         4          6          2          4          6         2         4
#6        20         20         27         27         27         6         6
#        X15       X16       X17       X18       X19       X20        X21
#1 (40, 188) (54, 202) (64, 212) (74, 222) (88, 236) (98, 246) (108, 256)
#5         6         2         4         6         2         4          6
#6         6        13        13        13        20        20         20
#         X22        X23        X24
#1 (122, 270) (132, 280) (142, 290)
#5          2          4          6
#6         27         27         27
```

Comment: Nice solution. I was thinking to do something with `melt`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, `melt` might be more general.  I assumed that the OP had only 3 rows.

Comment: Thanks for this. There are more rows, I just removed them for the example to make it simpler to understand.

Comment: @MichaelKrane  If there are more rows you may have to change the first line of code to `gr <- do.call(paste, as.data.frame(t(df1[-1,])))`  assuming that we will be comparing the columns in all the other rows except the first 1.

Comment: @akrun: Okay. Thanks again